# Determine how many ASP .NET MVC roles user has after login?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, roles

(Learning ASP .NET MVC 3).

How would I implement a method that would determine the number of ASP .NET roles the validated user belongs to?

```
if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
{
FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

//???? start
if(howManyRoles(mode.UserName) > 1)
{
   //get user to pick desire role
}

//???? end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SqlRoleProvider than something like this:

```
        public int howManyRoles()
        {
            var roleProvider = new SqlRoleProvider();
            var roles = roleProvider.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
            return roles.Length;
        }
```